Can I display texted formatted as html in CSV Downloader
I have reports that users can download into a .csv file but a few of the fields have HTML formatting from a WYSIWYG editor. Is there a way to display the HTML in the field in the .csv field?
Here is my ExportReport.jsx file:
import CsvDownloader from "react-csv-downloader";
import moment from "moment";

const ExportReport = ({ reports }) => {
  let columns = [];
  let datas = [];

  if (reports) {
    columns = [
      {
        id: "matchType",
        displayName: "Match Type",
      },
      {
        id: "eventName",
        displayName: "Event Name",
      },
      {
        id: "matchDate",
        displayName: "Match Date",
      },
      {
        id: "opponentName",
        displayName: "Opponent Name",
      },
      {
        id: "weightCategory",
        displayName: "Weight Category",
      },
      {
        id: "club",
        displayName: "Club",
      },
      {
        id: "country",
        displayName: "Country",
      },
      {
        id: "rank",
        displayName: "Rank",
      },
      {
        id: "grip",
        displayName: "Grip",
      },
      {
        id: "opponentAttacks",
        displayName: "Opponent Attacks",
      },
      {
        id: "attackNotes",
        displayName: "Opponent Attack Notes",
      },
      {
        id: "myAttacks",
        displayName: "My Attacks",
      },
      {
        id: "My Attack Notes",
        displayName: "My Attack Notes",
      },
      {
        id: "result",
        displayName: "Result",
      },
      {
        id: "score",
        displayName: "score",
      },
      {
        id: "videoURL",
        displayName: "Video URL",
      },
    ];

    let opponentAttacks = "";
    let athleteAttacks = "";

    reports.map((report) => {
      report.opponentAttacks.map((attack) => {
        opponentAttacks += attack + " ";
      });
      report.athleteAttacks.map((attack) => {
        athleteAttacks += attack + " ";
      });
      datas.push({
        matchType: report.matchType,
        eventName: report.eventName,
        matchDate: moment(report.matchDate).format("MM/DD/YYYY"),
        //endtDate: report.eventEndDate,
        opponentName: report.opponentName,
        weightCategory: report.weightCategory,
        club: report.club,
        country: report.country,
        rank: report.rank,
        grip: report.grip,
        opponentAttacks: opponentAttacks,
        attackNotes: report.opponentAttackNotes,
        myAttacks: athleteAttacks,
        myAttachNotes: report.athleteAttackNotes,
        result: report.result,
        scor: report.scor,
        videoURL: report.videoURL,
      });
    });
  }
  return (
    <CsvDownloader
      filename="matchReport"
      extension=".csv"
      separator=","
      //wrapColumnChar="'"
      columns={columns}
      datas={datas}
      text="Download Reports"
      className="profile_btn"
    />
  );
};

export default ExportReport;

The report.athleteAttackNotes and report.opponentAttackNotes have html formatting and I would like that to display as formatted in the .csv file if possible.
In a test report for the report.opponentAttacks I have  I have a test one in the .csv file that is:
<p>Rocky's attack notes</p><p><br></p><p><strong>Some Bold</strong></p>

and if at all possible I would like this text to be displayed with the spacing the <p></p> and <br> tags would provide in an HTML file.
I'm also not tied to a .csv file.  That was just the only solution I found to download the reports.  If there is some other way please let me know.

What sort of HTML formatting? Are they no longer valid CSV files?

I don't want the html tags to show up but want to know if I can format it.  Now for example I have a test one in the .csv file that is: Rocky's attack notesSome Bold.  I want it to have the spacing the  and  tags would provide in an html file, if possible.

That's not valid CSV at all; it's not really clear what you are asking. Anyway, your question needs to contain all the necessary information within the question itself (not in comments, behind external links, or in images or videos) and ideally nothing else.

There you go, I put in the comment to answer your question, but not it is in the question too.

I mean, CSV is plain text by definition. You can embed any text (including literal HTML tags) inside a quoted field, but I get the impression that's not what you want. This seems like an XY problem

I figured it out, and I get that the reason it wasn't working is because I was using .csv which is plain text so I found a way to download it to Excel which is keeping the formatting the way I wanted it.  I'll post my solution in a minute.  Thanks.

As suggested in the comments, thanks @tripleee.  My issue was that I was trying to display html in .csv which by definition is plain text, so I found another solution to download into Excel which keeps my formatting.
So I created a button on the page I was previously downloading the .csv from.  Then I created a table with all the data and added a button to export to excel.
I need to format it a bit, but here is the ReportsTable.jsx file:
const ReportsTable = ({ reports }) => {
  const exportTableToExcel = () => {
    // Get the table HTML
    const table = document.getElementById("my-table");
    if (!table) return;

    const tableHTML = table.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, "%20");

    // Specify the data type
    const dataType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

    // Define the file name
    const fileName = "table.xls";

    // Create a download link element
    const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

    // Browser check to support Microsoft Excel file download
    if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
      const blob = new Blob(["\ufeff", tableHTML], {
        type: dataType,
      });
      navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
    } else {
      // Create a link to the file
      downloadLink.href = `data:${dataType}, ${tableHTML}`;

      // Setting the file name
      downloadLink.download = fileName;

      // Triggering the function
      downloadLink.click();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <table id="my-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Match Type</th>
            <th>Event Name</th>
            <th>Match Date</th>
            <th>Opponent Name</th>
            <th>Weight Category</th>
            <th>Club</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Rank</th>
            <th>Grip</th>
            <th>Opponent Attacks</th>
            <th>Opponent Attack Notes</th>
            <th>My Attacks</th>
            <th>My Attack Notes</th>
            <th>Result</th>
            <th>Score</th>
            <th>Video URL</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {reports &&
            reports.map((report) => (
              <tr>
                <td>{report.matchType}</td>
                <td>{report.eventName}</td>
                <td>{moment(report.matchDate).format("MM/DD/YYYY")}</td>
                <td>{report.opponentName}</td>
                <td>{report.weightCategory}</td>
                <td>{report.club}</td>
                <td>{report.country}</td>
                <td>{report.rank}</td>
                <td>{report.grip}</td>
                <td>{report.opponentAttacks}</td>
                <td>
                  <div
                    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                      __html: `${report.opponentAttackNotes}`,
                    }}
                  />
                </td>
                <td>{report.athleteAttacks}</td>
                <td>
                  <div
                    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                      __html: `${report.athleteAttackNotes}`,
                    }}
                  />
                </td>
                <td>{report.result}</td>
                <td>{report.scor}</td>
                <td>{report.videoURL}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <button onClick={exportTableToExcel}>Export to Excel</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ReportsTable;

